# `less` performs differently when invoked from Bash and from Git

Tags: git, less

When I view a large diff with `git diff`, it gets paged with `less`. This is confirmed by opening another window and checking data from `ps -aux` and `/proc`.

However, when `less` is invoked by Git, it does not revert the terminal content to its previous state after hitting `q` (the diff content remains in terminal). But when I do

```
git diff commit1 commit2 --color | less -R
```

and quit `less` with a key `q`, the content disappears and the terminal reverts to the previous state.

More interestingly, if I do these

```
export PAGER=less LESS='-R'
```

and invoke `git diff` (or any other command that calls a pager), `less` behaves the same as if invoked directly from Bash shell.

> [image: i]

Here's a brief screenshot describing my question. On the left pane the command are executed as following:

```
unset PAGER GIT_PAGER LESS
git diff HEAD^ HEAD
```

On the right pane you see the commands. The latest commit was 100+ lines of `y` written to a file. On both panes `less` is exited with key `q`.

Can anyone tell me what is different and explain why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-corepager):

> When the `LESS` environment variable is unset, Git sets it to `FRX` (if `LESS` environment variable is set, Git does not change it at all).

The `-X` (`--no-init`) option is responsible for not clearing terminal after exit of `less`.

Comment: Wow, great answer! I'd like to know if there's a `git config` to change this behavior (change the `LESS` environment that Git sets).

Comment: @iBug Looks like it is baked into the [source](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3275838d969b7ecb91aae584226fccbeb046aca). Thus you need to build your own Git to change that.

Comment: I got Less 530 from FSF and compiled it myself. Now `less -FR` is very good to have. Thank you again!

Comment: There is no need to recompile less. You can simply turn off the default git options. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48511931/how-do-i-pass-options-to-less-from-git-diff

What you want is: `git config core.pager "less -+X -+F"` (turns off `-XF`) To set this globally instead of for a single project add `--global`