# Why is less being run unnecessarily by git?

Tags: git

When I run `git branch` (from bash or csh), it automagically pipes the output through `less`. However, with only a few branches in the repository this is beyond unnecessary, it is annoying, as the branch listing disappears once I quit less.

Checking `~/.gitconfig` file and the local `.git/config` files finds nothing about a pager or any thing else that would cause this. Otherwise, nothing I've found in web searches has been helpful or promising.

Why is this happening, and what (if anything) can I do to make `less` run when needed (e.g. when doing a `git log` when there's a lot of history) but not otherwise (like a `git branch` with only 2 or 3 branches)?

Comment: In general git doesn't know how much output there is going to be from any command, so it send everything by default through a pager, which will probably be less.

Comment: The first thing  do on a new -nix installation is to put `export LESS=-X` in the `.profile`. This [keeps less from "cleaning up"](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less) the screen. I *hate* it that the standard setting clears the screen because I often need to cut and paste stuff or use it as a reference.

Comment: @Peter To be clear (no pun intended), only people who don't want the screen clearing behavior should do that.

Comment: @icarus: That seems logical. However, the behavior of mine changed recently. I'm not sure why - probably a change to some environment variable forced from the corporate security folks "on high" who don't seem to care how difficult they make everyone else's jobs. Anyway, git suddenly went from what I considered sensible behavior to running single line outputs through less in such a way that  the output was lost when I stopped less.

Comment: If the behavior recently changed it is at least possible that a setting of the LESS variable was added to the system-wide shell startup files, e.g. /etc/profile, /etc/profile.d/*,  /etc/bash.bashrc, Do you have this variable in your environment?

Answer (score 50):

You can set the following:

```
git config --global core.pager 'less -FRX'
```

This will ensure that `less` will

- Exit if the entire file can be displayed on the first screen (`F`)
- Output the raw control characters for terminal formatting (`R`)
- <s>Chop long lines (`S`)</s>
- Don't send the init/de-init strings to the terminal - avoids clearing the screen on exit (`X`)

Edit: Removed the `S` option based on Peter A. Scheider's comment

Comment: and omit the `--global` if you want it to only apply to the current repository.

Comment: Setting the environment variable `LESS` to `-FR`, adding in X and S to taste is another way.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469360/less-performs-differently-when-invoked-from-bash-and-from-git?rq=1

Comment: Most likely the OP finds that behavior annoying in general; I suppose one could set the environment variable `export PAGER='less -FRSX'` and git would honor it (absent a specific git config). Btw, `-S` is dangerous because it silently discards output.

Answer (score 6):

There are some great answers here for tuning `less`'s behavior, but since my graybeard fingers are accustomed to typing `|more` when I want it, and since I'm still more in tune with mercurial than with git, I'm keen on

```
git config --global core.pager cat
```

Comment: The man page for `git-config` states that the value of `core.pager` is intended to be interpreted by the shell. When you set it to `no`, it tries to execute the command `no`, which most likely doesn't exist, then it falls back to simply outputting the contents. You will still see an error message at the head. What you probably want to do is to set it to `cat` instead.

Comment: That's a good piece of information, but what I like is that it doesn't execute _anything_. The `cat` is useless, and I don't particularly trust Linux util maintainers not to change what cat does (cf. [the `ls` quoted files debacle](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258679)). Maybe I should use "don't ever" instead. It's less likely that such a program exists.

Comment: Setting `core.pager` to the empty string (`git config core.pager ''`) or to `cat` will __not__ run anything at all. You can work it out yourself if you don't believe me ;-) There's no reason whatsoever to set it to a dummy command like `no`.

Comment: Great, thanks! I had no idea the empty string would cause no command execution. As to `cat`, are you saying that git has a special case for that string in the pager code — i.e. that `cat` is effectively a synonym for "null"? I would expect it to execute `cat`.

Comment: This indeed seems to be the case. Egads. But also good: I'm always looking for more ways to justify my distaste for git.