# How does a command decide when to invoke a pager?

Tags: pager

Some shell commands that produce large outputs, such as `git diff`, seem to cleverly throw up a pager when the output is too long, but not do so if it happens to be small.

How does this work? Does each individual program have its own code to measure its output, and invoke the pager? By the time it realizes the output is too long, wouldn't it have already printed some to stdout with no way to get it back? Or is this a generic shell feature where any program can be made to take advantage of it even if not explicitly programmed to do so?

To be clear: Of course `foo | less` will force a pager and `foo | cat` will force no pager. What I'm wondering is if there's a way to make any arbitrary `foo` behave as `foo | pager_if_needed`. I also don't mean literally implementing `pager_if_needed` (probably can be done in 2-3 lines of bash) and doing `alias foo="foo | pager_if_needed"` - since that would not also apply to `bar`, `baz`, and everything else.

Comment: Related: [Why is less being run unnecessarily by git?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/536727)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does the shell decide when to invoke a pager?

It doesn't.

> Does each individual program have its own code to measure its output, and invoke the pager?

Yes.

> By the time it realizes the output is too long, wouldn't it have already printed some to stdout with no way to get it back?

Simple: only start printing your output *after* you have checked whether it is too long.

Comment: for the last one, I think `git` relies on `less -F` to have _less itself_ exit if the output fits the screen.

Comment: But I assume only if Git uses `less`, correct? The pager for Git can be configured separately for each command per repository, per user, and per system, as well as using the `GIT_PAGER` and `PAGER` environment variables.

Comment: Yes, and even with `less`, you could set `LESS` to something that doesn't include `-F`, and you'll see the pager appear if the output from the Git command is short enough. What I mean is that it looks to me that Git doesn't really care how long the output is, but instead punts that part of the UI to the pager.

Comment: @ilkkachu Ah so `less -F` is already behaving like the hypothetical `pager_if_needed` from my question. Neat.